# Which are the most fundamental theorems in core undergrad math?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, statistics

I want to compile the most important theorems for Calculus, Linear Algebra, and introductory ODE, PDE, probability and statistics.
These should be the most important 5/10 per "subject", to put an arbitrary limit.
You may want to contribute with your LA list as an example, and a brief explanation on your choice above others.

Comment: This question does not fit the guidelines for this site very well. It's too subjective, too broad, and does not have a conclusive answer. Perhaps you'd have better luck on Quora.

Comment: Conley's theorem (or "fundamental theorem of dynamical systems", as the related school calls it): There exists a complete Lyapunov function for any homeomorphism on a compact metric space. 99.9% of the experts would disagree that it is appropriate to refer to it as "fundamental". Anyways, the term was coined by Norton as late as in 1995 (!). In other words: your question is too broad for people to agree on what are "the most important theorems".

Comment: Try Quora for these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Jonas, I changed it to fundamental. I don´t expect a 100% agreement by everyone, but for sure there are some theorems that are in each and every book and the most basics of those (the others are somehow based on them) are the ones I´m looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Warning: this list is incomplete and written by a noob:

Calculus:

- Theorem saying a continuous function on a closed bounded interval reaches max and min
- Intermediate value theorem
- Mean Value Theorem
- Theorem saying a real sequence is Cauchy if and only if it converges
- Fundamental theorem of calculus
- Green's Theorem

Linear Algebra

- Theorem saying every finitely generetad vector space has dimension (so every basis has same size)
- Rank/nullity theorem
- Cayley Hamilton theorem
- Spectral theorem

Group theory:

- Lagrange's theorem
- Cauchy's theorem
- Sylow's theorem
- Orbit-Stabilizer theorem
- Burnside's lemma
- The isomorphism theorems

Complex analysis

- Cauchy-Goursat theorem
- Cauchy's integral formula
- Taylor's theorem
- Laurent's theorem
- The residue theorem

Comment: I would now add the equivalence of norms theorem, the theorem saying continuous with compact domain is uniformly continuous, theorem about existence of solutions to diferential equations and much more tbh